# BecomeFirstResponder in viewdidload make the views goes up in iOS 10

Tags: objective-c, xcode8, ios10

i have issue with becomeFirstReponder, in iOS 9 , the views keep remain in their spot, but when i upgrade my Xcode to Xcode 8 and compile it with iOS 10, the views move to the top (out of screen) when the keyboard begins to appear.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

[self.usernameTextField becomeFirstResponder];
}
```

Is there any other solution to make the keyboard is appear without moving other element to the top?

Comment: I am not sure but try to write this code in viewDidAppear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have also faced this issue.

Just use view's `layoutIfNeeded` before `becomeFirstResponder`

```
[self.view layoutIfNeeded];
```

Try like this :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
    [self.usernameTextField becomeFirstResponder];

}
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: @calvinsugianto Welcome anytime :)

Comment: @AshishKakkad Why does this happen?